# Integral of measurable subset of nonnegative measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function on bounded measurable set $A$. For $B\subset A$ measurable subset, then $\int_{B}fdm\leq\int_{A}fdm$. How to prove this ? Is there any particular hint ? (If I use the definition of supremum , I still need to prove $\int_{B}f_1dm\leq\int_{A}f_1dm$ for simple function $f_1\leq f$ for which I don't know how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: This isn't true unless $f\geq 0$...assuming this though, this follows by just noting that any simple function that is pointwise dominated by $f\chi_B$ is also pointwise dominated by $f\chi_A$.

Comment: @user293121 your first statement is false. the inequality can certainly be true even if $f$ is sometimes negative

Comment: What is mean by point wise dominated ?

Comment: @LingMinHao a function $f$ pointwise dominates a function $g$ if $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for each $x$.

Comment: @mathworker21 it doesn't matter that the inequality can sometimes be true, the general statement that was to proved requires it be true for all $B\subseteq A$, which fails unless $f\geq 0$ a.e.

Comment: @user293121 I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't matter". You shouldn't be making false statements.

Comment: @mathworker21 The original statement was "suppose $f$ is a measurable function on a bounded measurable set $A$. For $B\subseteq A$ a measurable subset, $\int_B f\,dm\leq \int_A f\, dm$." I think the only reasonable way to adjudicate the truth of this statement is to say this statement is true iff it holds for all measurable $B\subseteq A$, not just some $B\subseteq A$ (obviously $B=A$ will always work). The inequality will not hold for all $B$ unless $f\geq 0$ a.e. on $A$, just by letting $B$ be the support of the positive part of $f$. Please enlighten me what part is "false."

Comment: @user293121 sorry, you're right. I misread your previous comment. thanks!

Comment: @user293121, how to show any simple function that is pointwise dominated by $f_{\mathbb{X}_{B}}$ is also pointwise dominated by $f_{\mathbb{X}_{A}}$ I mean, I know the idea, just I don't know how to write properly.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\phi$ is a simple function such that $0 \leqslant \phi \leqslant f \chi_B$.  Since $f \chi_B \leqslant f$ on $A$ it follows that $\phi \leqslant f$ on $A$, and

$$\int_A \phi \leqslant \sup_{\phi \leqslant f }\int_A \phi =\int_Af $$

Thus, $\int_Af $ is an upper bound for $\int_A \phi$ for every $\phi \leqslant f \chi_B$, and

$$\int_Bf := \int_Af \chi_B = \sup_{\phi \leqslant f\chi_B}\int_A \phi \leqslant \int_A f$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x$ in $B$ and $g(x)=0$ otherwise.  Then $\int_A g=\int_B f$.  However $g\le f$ on $A$, so $\int_A g\le \int_A f$.  Therefore $\int_B f\le \int_A f$.